# MySQL: Delete rows after selecting them

Tags: mysql, console

On my MySQL console I run this

```
SELECT option_name FROM blog_options WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_timeout%' AND option_value < now();
```

And I get a list of rows in option_name table. What should I add in the code above to delete the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM blog_options 
WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_timeout%' 
AND option_value < now();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
```

Is used to display data. You can also `UPDATE DELETE INSERT` and many other commands

In this case you want to delete so you should use this query

```
DELETE FROM blog_options 
WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_timeout%' 
AND option_value < now();
```

Answer (score 1):

use `DELETE` instead of `SELECT option_name` and execute the query.